# How can I eliminate invalid volume specification error when using docker-compose to create a named volume for sql db in Windows Container?

Tags: sql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to use docker-compose to create a named volume for sql db in Windows container.

I keep getting the error:
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Building webpresentation
Recreating dockercompose6946136170613312467_webpresentation_1 ... 
Creating dockercompose6946136170613312467_db_1                ... 
Creating dockercompose6946136170613312467_db_1                ... error
ERROR: for dockercompose6946136170613312467_db_1  Cannot create container for service db: invalid volume specification: 'dockercompose6946136170613312467_sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql:rw'
Recreating dockercompose6946136170613312467_webpresentation_1 ... done
ERROR: for db  Cannot create container for service db: invalid volume specification: 'dockercompose6946136170613312467_sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql:rw'
Encountered errors while bringing up the project..

For more troubleshooting information, go to http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting    docker-compose  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets 363 "

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
    version: '3.4'

services:
  webpresentation:
    image: webpresentation
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebPresentation\Dockerfile

  db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: Test1
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql

volumes:
  sqlvolume:
```

I should also mention that I've used Visual Studio's Docker tools to set this project up here is the docker-compose.override.yml file as well:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webpresentation:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "80"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to eliminate this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is having this problem, the project successfully built in Visual Studio after I did a `docker volume ls` and realized the actual volume name had an auto-generated "dockercompose" prefix. I used a more direct path to the folder on the hard drive in the db's volume definition. I then replaced every instance of "sqlvolume" with the new name. My complete docker-compose file is as follows:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webpresentation:
    image: webpresentation
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebPresentation\Dockerfile

  db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: Test1
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\volumes\\dockercompose6946136170613312467_sqlvolume:c:\\mssql"

volumes:
  dockercompose6946136170613312467_sqlvolume:
```

Comment: Just one note here: not a good idea doing it this way. What will happen if you run the same composer file on a different system? It may happen that your volume path is not available.

Comment: Maybe can solve it by using docker-compose.override.yaml or .env files to avoid messing with other unexpecting developers.